# pandas: Match data by months and days

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, merge, concatenation

How can I match data only by months and dates and not by year:

[1. Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B590e.png)

[2. Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNe1u.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert `Time` column to datetimes and then to custom format `MM/DD/` and then aggregate:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).dt.strftime('%m/%d/')

df1 = df.groupby('Time').first()
```

If need aggregate `sum`, `mean` if duplicates use:

```
df2 = df.groupby('Time').sum(min_count=1)
df3 = df.groupby('Time').mean()
```